# Why won't my Gmail e-mails sent from Outlook show up in the users inbox? (Webmail works fine)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

For some reason whenever I try to sent an e-mail from Outlook, using a Gmail account, the e-mail will not show up in the user's inbox. This goes for both new messages and replies to earlier received conversations. Everything was working fine a few hours ago.

The e-mail does show up in Gmail's sent items, and when I view the full headers, the message status is "delivered".

When trying from webmail, it works fine....

Already tried:

- Rebooting PC
- Removing and Re-adding account

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using oath2 for authentication?

Comment: Just using the outlook desktop client, so everything is handled by it. No errors, it worked fine a few hours ago, and the mails show up in Gmail's sent items and are marked as delivered..

Comment: Oh, and they don't show up in spam either.

Comment: what version of outlook? Gmail has been phasing out ["less secure apps"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) starting recently, and this might be an effect. You will have to sign in to gmail using an app password or oath2, not just a username and password.

Comment: The newest, and that is not the issue because it worked fine just a few hours ago...

Comment: not necessarily, I assume they won't make everything stop working instantly, but rather slowly phase it out for different users at different times. So the fact that it used to work (even after the official end date) is no proof that it still works. Did you ever enable less secure apps? If not, then for sure that's not the issue, but if you did at some point that may be the issue.

Comment: you have to enable 2-step verification in gmail, and then sign in with outlook

Comment: Im pretty sure that is not the issue... The E-mail shows up in sent items and receiving mails works fine.

Comment: sounds like the problem is with the receiver. what happens if you send an email to yourself?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes the issue self resolved a few days later and we will not be able to tell the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue is more related to your recipient, it is recommended that the recipient go to the web to check whether the email has been received.
Besides, use search filter to check if the email is moved to other folder by rules.

Comment: Actually, I was the recipient, was testing between my own adresses. It suddenly worked again

Comment: Glad that you issue has been resolved!

Answer (score -2):

Seems this was some kind of server glitch, it works again now.

Comment: This is THE answer, but it means the source question should be closed and deleted as it cannot be recreated and the issue was not due to computer hardware problems r software within the limits defined in the Help section.